# Delete an item in d3 js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

You are using some caption items. When you click on a caption item, d3 should delete it. For this, I made a function that removes an item from the data array so that d3 excludes this item from the DOM.

Array with data:

```
[   
    { key: "Product 1", total: 300 }​,
    { key: "Product 2", total: 606 }, 
    { key: "Product 3", total: 151 }​, 
    { key: "Product 4", total: 60 }​
]
```

Code d3 to write the captions of the chart:

```
    svg.select("#legend")
        .selectAll("text")
        .data(dataNest)
        .exit()
        .remove()

    svg.select("#legend")
        .selectAll("text")
        .data(dataNest)
        .enter()
        .append("text")
        .attr("id", d => d.key)
        .attr("x", (d, i) => (legendSpace/2)+i*legendSpace)
        .attr("y", height + (margin.bottom/2) + 15)
        .text(d => d.key)
        .on("click", d => this.removeLegend(d.key))
```

Function that removes the clicked item from the array:

```
this.addRemoveArea(d.key)
```

With each click, regardless of the clicked item, d3 always removes the last caption (first remove Product 4, then Product 3 ...) until the captions are finished. Is there any way to associate the clicked element with the data output that corresponds to that element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. Just relate the data in the .data() function.

```
.data(dataNest, d => d.key)
```